# How to pin Chrome to the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

How can I pin Chrome browser to the task bar next to the icons you see in the attached image? I have tried to drag the chrome shortcut there but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Start menu.
2. Type "Chrome".
3. Right-click Chrome icon.
4. Click *Pin to taskbar*.